# Problem with mysql_fetch_row() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get data from a database. I have the following code for that:

```
mysql_select_db($database_tony, $tony);
$query_rsTony = "SELECT `tony feature`.`text` 
                   FROM `tony feature`";

$rsTony = mysql_query($query_rsTony, $tony)) ;
if ($rsTony) echo 'set';
else echo 'not set'; 
$row_rsTony = mysql_fetch_row($rsTony)); 
if ($row_rsTony) echo 'set';
else echo 'not set';
$totalRows_rsTony = mysql_num_rows($rsTony);
$text = $row_rsTony['text'];
```

I am getting the output:

set not set

**EDIT**
I added the changes said below and I have the above output. 
I don't know why the `mysql_fetch_row($rsTony)` is not working -- any ideas?

Comment: Is the query returning any rows?  What does $totalRows_rsTony tell you?

Comment: As a side, I would strong suggest a better database naming convention (i.e. no spaces) and encourage the use of curly braces for all control structure blocks (i.e. if/else).

Comment: Thank you. I'll implement that. But is there anything wrong with the syntax or logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use result which returned by `mysql_query` as `mysql_fetch_row` parameter:

```
$rsTony = mysql_query($query_rsTony, $tony)) ;
if ($rsTony) echo 'set';
else echo 'not set';
```

**UPDATE**

```
$row_rsTony = mysql_fetch_row($rsTony)); 
if ($row_rsTony) echo 'set';
else echo 'not set';
//....
```

So, you final code should look like

```
$rsTony = mysql_query($query_rsTony, $tony)) ;
if ($rsTony) echo 'set';
else echo 'not set';
$row_rsTony = mysql_fetch_row($rsTony)); 
if ($row_rsTony) echo 'set';
else echo 'not set';
```

Comment: I am using the result from mysql_query as a parameter in mysql_fetch_row.

Comment: But you set `$rsTony` on the top of your code. Then you execute a bunch of other queries, but don't change `$rsTony`, it is still a result of the very first query execution.

Comment: got it. thank you. but if I do if($row_rsTony) it returns false. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: It's still the same problem, you need to add `$row_rsTony = mysql_fetch_row($rsTony);` instead of (`if(mysql_fetch_row($rsTony)) echo "set";`).

Comment: Did I do what you asked me to? I am sorry. the $row_rsTony is returning false.

Comment: Please check my edit now. I am still getting set set not set.

Comment: I put it all together. See if it helps

Comment: I made the changes. I got set not set. any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the query returns at least 1 row?

Comment: yeah. i have a row in my database. I am sure.

Comment: @Brahadeesh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1519/discussion-between-a1ex07-and-brahadeesh)

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks funny. Try this:

```
$query_rsTony = "SELECT text FROM feature";
```

Comment: His table name looks funny. The query is just fine.

Comment: the mysql_query works. I get the same result even if I make the change